# Guava Hashing Use Cases

Tags: hash, guava

I am looking at new features available in Guava and I have found a page on [hashing utilities](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/HashingExplained).

The documentation says that

> For the many uses of hash functions beyond simple hash tables,
>   however, Object.hashCode almost always falls short

Can you please share some other use cases of hash functions beyond hash tables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Cryptographic hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), [Bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), [data fingerprinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_%28computing%29), [the Rabin-Karp substring-search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), should I go on?